# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Join'

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

New to ASP.net and MVC and everything so far has come along nicely. Got to databases today and WHAT!? I'm pretty confused, and unsure where I've gone wrong here. I'm trying to use LINQ to SQL (at least, I think I am..). Let me give you the scenario of the database to help you understand better what the code is doing.

We have three tables, Inventory, Location and Equipment. Inventory contains all the data of what is in stock, names etc. Location contains LocationID and LocationName, whilst Equipment contains EquipmentID and EquipmentName. Inventory contains both EquipmentID and LocationID too.

I want to show the Station Reference, Equipment (EquipmentID turning into EquipmentName) and Location (LocationID turning into EquipmentName).

I've got the following code:

```
InventoryDataContext context = new InventoryDataText();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    IList<InventoryModel> inventoryList = new List<InventoryModel>();
    var query = from tblInventory in context
                join tblEquipment in context
                on tblInventory.EquipmentID equals tblEquipment.EquipmentID
                join tblLocation in context
                on tblInventory.LocationID equals tblLocation.LocationID
                select new InventoryModel {
                    InventoryID = tblInventory.InventoryID,
                    StationReference = tblInventory.StationReference,
                    EquipmentID = tblEquipment.EquipmentID,
                    EquipmentName = tblEquipment.EquipmentName,
                    LocationID = tblLocation.LocationID,
                    LocationName = tblLocation.LocationName
                };

}
```

Everything seems to be fine other than one error, which is:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'InventoryDataContext'. 'Join' not found.

It's the first context that seems to be giving the error (`var query = from tblInventory in context`).

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect. You need to specify which table in the context to use.

```
var query = from inv in context.tblInventory 
            join eq in context.tblEquipment
              on inv .EquipmentID equals eq .EquipmentID
```

Comment: Doing that gives me "'InventoryDataContext' does not contain a definition for tblInventory and no extension method tblInventory accepting a first argument type 'InventoryDataContext' could be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sometimes linq pluralities the table names.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause errors on 'InventoryID = tblInventory.InventoryID'? As that's the only line that gets the errors.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now :). Got another issue but will research it and see if it's related and if so post the solution to that and set this as answered.

Comment: Tried to research the issue, but to no avail. Tried doing what the error message says, quite literally but still didn't work. 'The name tblInventories is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'. Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'. This is where it says 'on tblInventories.EquipmentID equals tblEquipment.EquipmentID'. I swapped it round so tblEquipment.EquipmentID came first, but it just changed the error to right side, rather than left side. Any ideas?